# Custom JSF Scope "TabScope" for Primefaces Tabs

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, scope, tabview, view-scope

I am trying to create a dynamic tab where selecting a row from the Master tab creates a tab dynamically and added to the Primefaces TabView without leaving the main application page. I am using a Master page (Ex. countryMaster.xhtml) for the master tab and RE-using the detail page for each row selected (Ex: countryDetail.xhtml) for the detail tab.

I would like to create a custom "TabScope" custom scope based from ViewScope, wherein I can bind the detail Tab's tabId to the backing bean and stored in the ViewMap.

1. How can I achieve this?
2. Is this possible?
3. How do I get the tabId of the tab that is using the backing bean instance?

Thanks!!

Ex:

```
public class TabScope implements Scope {

    public Object get(String name, ObjectFactory objectFactory) {


    Map<String,Object> viewMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap();  



        String tabId = null;
        //Get tabId that uses this backing bean


        if (tabId != null) {
            if (viewMap.containsKey(name)) {
                final Object object = viewMap.get(name);
                if (object instanceof Map<?, ?>) {
                    final Map<String, Object> mapObject = (Map<String, Object>) object;

                    if (mapObject.containsKey(tabId)) {
                        return mapObject.get(tabId);
                    }                   
                }               
            }   
            Object object = objectFactory.getObject();

            Map<String, Object> tabIdBeanMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);              
            tabIdBeanMap.put(tabId, object);

            viewMap.put(name, tabIdBeanMap);

            return object;
        } else {
            String message = "TabId not found.";
            facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, message, null));

            return null;
        }       
    }
```

Comment: It turns out that I'm looking for something similar ... was this achieved at the end ? Any workable solution ?